# How to efficiently create images of overlapping, semi-transparent circles in python

Tags: python, visualization, genetic-algorithm

I am privately working on a genetic algorithm that should approximate a picture using colored circles, similar to [this example written in javascript](https://chriscummins.cc/s/genetics/).

The algorithm includes a function to create a picture from the internal representation of an individual, which is used to calculate its [fitness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_function), and therefore needs to be executed frequently.

Find below a minimal working code example that creates a picture looking exactly how I want it, **but in too much time**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
import numpy as np
from random import randint


class Circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = (randint(0, 200), randint(0, 200))
        self.radius = randint(5, 50)
        self.color = self.to_hex(randint(0, 256**4))

    @staticmethod
    def to_hex(number, length=8):
        h = hex(number)[2:]
        while len(h) < length:
            h = "0" + h
        return h


def create_picture(circles, show=False):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
    plt.xlim(0, 200)
    plt.ylim(0, 200)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0, hspace=0, wspace=0)
    plt.margins(0, 0)
    for c in circles:
        new = plt.Circle(c.position, c.radius, facecolor="#" + c.color, edgecolor=None)
        ax.add_patch(new)
    ax.axis('off')
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    canvas.draw()
    width, height = fig.get_size_inches() * fig.get_dpi()
    img = np.frombuffer(canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8').reshape(int(height), int(width), 3)
    if show:
        plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)
    return img

create_picture([Circle() for _ in range(100)], True)
```

My question is: How can I create such a picture in python (not necessarily matplotlib) in a more efficient way?

I have tried using PIL but I wasn't able to get the transparency part working there.
I have also tried calculating the picture in numpy by calculating each pixel, which was even slower than my plt solution.

I would be very happy about ideas to speed up my code or an alternative approach.

Comment: The next thing to try is the computer vision library, opencv. I have seen examples of transparent figures, but havn't tried it myself

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will try to work out a solution with opencv tomorrow and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try OpenCV. Unfortunately, it can't draw semitransparent circles out-of-box, you have to first draw a circle and then merge the result with the original, which may slow down the process. But worth trying.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def draw_circle(image, center, radius, color, alpha):
    overlay = image.copy()
    cv2.circle(image, center, radius, color, -1)
    cv2.addWeighted(image, alpha, overlay, 1 - alpha, 0, image)

im = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), np.uint8) + 255
draw_circle(im, (80, 80), 40, (255, 0, 0), 0.5)
draw_circle(im, (100, 100), 40, (0, 255, 0), 0.5)
draw_circle(im, (120, 120), 40, (0, 0, 255), 1/3)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will come back at this tomorrow and let you know if it produced a speedup.

Comment: I actually could not wait till tomorrow. I have tried the method and the speedup is significant. Therefore I accepted your answer. I will find out how to crop the image and remove axes by myself. Thank you again!

Comment: You don't need to crop anything, I put `imshow` here just to visualize the result. You already have the image in `im`. If you need to save it into a file, just use `cv2.imwrite("filename.png", im)`